# How to read text from custom keyboard from third party apps like skype, whats up and so on?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, keyboard-events, custom-keyboard

How to read text from custom keyboard from third party apps like Skype, whats up and so on?

Step1: I have to create custom keyboard in swift ios

Step2: Enable and add custom keyboard in ios device.

Step3: User will open skype and chat using custom keyboard .

Step 4: I need to read text or detect text or get text , user typed text from third party apps like skype , whats up, message and so on.

Eg: User open skype and chat using custom keyboard like "Hello" . I wants to read text or get text or detect text as Hello using ios swift.

Comment: #1 if you have created custom keyboard, then you are the one who implemented creating the text from the keyboard -> it should be super easy to record the user input (since you are generating it), #2 this is something Apple is very sensitive of.. recording the text and leaking it anywhere might very easily end in rejection of the custom keyboard

Comment: Thanks Milan . But my question is how to read the text from third party app. for example I am sent a message via Skype "Hello Milan" using my owned custom keyboard . how to get text or read text or hack text as "Hello Milan"

Answer (score 0):

If you have created your own custom keyboard, then you are the one who implemented creating the text from the keyboard -> it should be super easy to record the user input (since you are generating it). E.g., if you generate a character using:

```
self.textDocumentProxy.insertText(characterString)
```

Then just at the same moment track that character:

```
self.textGeneratedInThisSession = self.textGeneratedInThisSession + characterString
```

Assuming there is `textGeneratedInThisSession` variable into which you are appending the text.

Moreover, at any moment you can just examine the content of `self.textDocumentProxy` which gives you the power to find out even the content of the document proxy that was generated by other keyboards, e.g.:

```
let contentDescription = textDocumentProxy.description
```

Read more in [UITextDocumentProxy](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextdocumentproxy) documentation.

---

However, you should know that this is something Apple is very sensitive about. Recording the text and leaking it anywhere might very easily end in rejection of the custom keyboard.

Comment: Great . Thanks Milan . how we can read the skype text  (user typed text) in third party. you can say as self.textGeneratedInThisSession  . how it is to be invoke , from where ? can u pls explian in detail .

Comment: @suripappuRengan if you implemented a cusotm keyboard as you claim you did, you had to invoke `self.textDocumentProxy.insertText(characterString)` somewhere.. that means you can take that `characterString` there and use it anyhow you want.. store it, send it, etc. just do that

Comment: ok i accept it .self.textDocumentProxy.insertText(characterString) we use to update the text in current custom keyboard . This is not my issues. My issues is how to read text from third party app like SKYPE , WHATS UP and all.